# FaunaDB returns multiple instances of the same item due to an array attribute, why?

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, faunadb

as the title say I am currently using FaunaDB for a React application to manage inventories. Each item in my inventory collection has a sales "attribute" which is an array like such :

```
"data": {
    "sales": [["2021/2/5",2],["2021/2/9",1],["2021/2/11",1],["2021/2/16",1]]
}
```

When using an index returning data.sales , Fauna returns me the same item multiple times because it destructures my sales array. Here's an example using the array from my previous example :
[screenshot of my index return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiwB5.png).
As you can see it sends me the same item multiple time but with a different value from my array each time. I would like to get my item only one time per request, with the whole array as an "attribute", how can I do this ?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the index for such documents?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/srz17IK)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the output from running `Get(Index("the_name_of_your_index"))`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Fauna creates a separate index entry for each element in an array.  There are at least a few ways to handle this.

### serialize the array into a string

@eskwayrd asked for the Index definition, but since we don't have that, so I am guessing that you might only be using the sales field as values, and not as terms.

If you are not searching by the dates, then you can serialize the whole field as a JSON string.  When you need to use it you can parse it.

```
"data": {
    "sales": `[["2021/2/5",2],["2021/2/9",1],["2021/2/11",1],["2021/2/16",1]]`
}
```

### Denormalize the sales array into a different Collection

You might consider this if you need to search by any of the values in the lower array, like the date or other values.

For example:

```js
Create(Collection("employees"), {
  data: { name: "Paul" }
})
```

```js
Create(Collection("sales_stats"), {
  data: {
    employee: Ref(Collection("employees")),
    date: Date("2021-02-05"),
    count: 1
  }
})
```

### Aggregate the data in FQL (but probably client-side)

FQL is flexible enough to perform aggregation tasks.  For example, you can use the `Reduce` function to scan over the results and perform operations like group, sum, count, etc.

This can be helpful if you really need to reduce the size of the payload over the network.

However, be careful about deciding to do a lot of general compute on the database, since it can cost a lot more in the long run to use a lot of Compute resources.  See the [Billing docs page](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/concepts/billing) for more details on that.